# Entity reference with ddf, dynamic dependent fields

Tags: entities

I'm not able to configure ddf module, I followed the instructions but still nothing.

I'm sure is the best module for my necessity.

I have a content type "house" with a field "rooms" with cardinality +1.

In another content type I have a field "house", an entity reference of the "house" c. type and a dependent select list of rooms that should be updated by the value chosen on the precedent field.

I installed the ddf module, I created the view with the contextual filter and configured the dependent value with dynamic argument.

Unfortunately I'm missing something and the dependent value doesn't reload with the correct values.

Any tip will be much appreciated !

Comment: By ddf, you mean the Dynamic Dependent Fields module, correct? Also, are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm using Drupal 7 and the module is dynamic dependent fields 

Answer (score 0):

DDF is a complex-looking module but there are only a few areas where you might make a mistake.  Try enabling the submodule "DDF Entity Reference" on the modules page if you have not done so already.  If you are still having problems after enabling the submodule, post here and I'll take another look at your entity reference view setup.